# How do I create redirects in Umbraco when old pages have same directory as new pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex, umbraco

I currently have an old web site running on asp. I have URLs like:

http://www.domain.com/products/cars/fastcar.asp

The new site is in Umbraco 4.11 and the same page has a URL like this:

http://www.domain.com/products/our-fast-cars/fast-car.aspx

I created the following redirect rule in UrlRewriting.config:

```
<add name="CMSUpgrade301-26" virtualUrl="~/products/cars/fastcar.asp" destinationUrl="~/products/our-fast-cars/fast-car.aspx" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" redirect="Application" redirectMode="Permanent" ignoreCase="true" />
```

The site doesn't appear to do a redirect, instead attempting to load the path:

http://www.domain.com/products.aspxcars/fastcars.asp

When I go to the URL:

http://www.domain.com/products/cars/fastcar.asp

I suspect it has something to do with the MVC routes being processed before the re-write rules but I am not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: The path you have defined in the UrlRewriting.config is different to the path in you question. One is fastcars.asp and the other is fastcar.asp. Could you check this?

Comment: Also, you say "the site doesn't pick up the redirect" but then you say you "get redirected". Why do you get redirected at all?

Comment: @Digbyswift I edited the question to fix the type on the URL. When I say the site doesn't pick up the redirect I mean it doesn't redirect to the page I specify, instead it loads the broken path I listed.

Answer (score 0):

this will tell you how MVC is interpreting the route
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: I am not sure I could add this to the Umbaco infrastructure.